# Phalcon is not loading Incubator Files

Tags: php, phalcon

I have registered `Phalcon` namespace in my loader correctly as I have done it any other namespaces so far.

For some reason I can't seem to load Phalcon incubator files in my project.

I'm using `Phalcon\Loader` to register namespaces and I can clearly see registered namespace via `spl_autoload_functions()`

`["Phalcon"]=>"/var/www/html/project/apps/vendor/phalcon/incubator/"`

And full path of the class file is `/var/www/html/project/apps/vendor/phalcon/incubator/Utils/Slug.php`

Unfortunately I keep getting class not found error when I try to use incubator classes;

```
namespace AppName\Models

use Phalcon\Utils\Slug;

class MyModel 
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $slug = Slug::generate("testing slug");
        var_dump($slug);
    }
}
```

Result:
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phalcon\\Utils\\Slug' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your file & folder permissions. If they are not accessible due to permissions, class files won't load.

Comment: Thank you, it was the permissions. I didn't think about checking them out. I just copied and pasted the files & folders.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Phalcon/Loader`?

```
$loader = new Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Phalcon' => '/path/to/incubator/Library/Phalcon/'
));

$loader->register();
```

https://github.com/phalcon/incubator#autoloading-from-the-incubator

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `Phalcon\Loader` I'm just checking if namespaces registered correctly via `spl_autoload_functions()`